# Unit testing of "renaming files" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

Suppose I have the following function and I need to unit test it:

```
def move_files_to(files, path):
for file in files:
    os.rename(file, path + "/" + file)
```

my thoughts on this topic:

Mocking os.rename would lead to no outcome, on the other hand, having files and renaming them would be "doing I/O" which should be avoided in unit tests. Please correct me, if I am wrong. Does testing make sense here?

Comment: You can create a dummy file, move it, do a `os.path.exists` to make sure it got moved then delete it, still IO but sometimes those tests can be useful for catching exceptings you can't catch with monkeypatching.

Comment: If you mock `os.rename()` out, you can still assert that it was called with the expected parameters. In general, I don't think that kind of test provides much value, since you basically need to reimplement the function to assert it makes the right calls to `os.rename()`, but it still helps to ensure the function does not contain any mistyped identifier etc.

Comment: @SvenMarnach why don't you post this as answer? To me it sounds as the most reasonable solution

Comment: @SvenMarnach I would also do a `path` check to make sure both paths provided to `os.rename` are valid.

Comment: @David I simply don't feel there is a "right" answer here. In many cases, I personally wouldn't unit test this function. It is very simple, pylint will catch most typos, and maybe there is an integration test that covers this function in some way. But it all depends on the context, the testing philosophy of the project and your personal preferences, so I preferred to write this as a comment.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to test `os.rename`, but *your* code needs to be tested. In your particular case the simplest way is to patch `os.rename`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_move_files():
    files = ['a.txt', 'b.txt']
    path = 'old'
    expected = [(('a.txt', 'old/a.txt'),),
                (('b.txt', 'old/b.txt'),)]
    with patch('os.rename') as rename:
        move_files_to(files, path)
        assert rename.call_args_list == expected
```

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be

create a `DirectoryTestCase(unittest.TestCase)` with

1. a setup that i) removes a (non-tracked) directory if it exists (e.g. `_tests` under `tests/`) ii) creates an empty directory and iii) copies (test) files to it.
2. a teardown that removes the directory

Second, create the tests under that test case. You can test moving to same directory (rename), to a new directory (under the test directory, should it create if it does not exist or fail?) move a symlink, etc., all under the encapsulation of the existing directory.

If you want tests to run in parallel, give the directory a unique (random but valid) name.

Example code:

```
import unittest
import shutil
import os
import string
import random


class DirectoryTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    test_files = ['file.txt']

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        unique_string = ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=10))

        self.path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '_temp' + unique_string)

        shutil.rmtree(self.path, ignore_errors=True)

        os.makedirs(self.path, exist_ok=True)

        for file in self.test_files:
            shutil.copy(file, self.path)

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        shutil.rmtree(self.path, ignore_errors=True)

    def test_basic(self):
        # validate the existence of the file, not an actual test.
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.path, 'file.txt')))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. since it is a difficulty to mock OS module in python, you can ignore to write unitest
2. But unit test means to validate your single method with some possible scenarios, so if you think that must validate all time. then a unit test is a must.